# Using async in MVC for actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm new to `async` so I apologize in advance if the answer is obvious. In MVC if I wanted to run a task that has no impact on the data being returned (ex. analytics) can `async` void be helpful or would you just fire off a completely dif thread. If I understand correctly using `async` void would not help for this case because we're still not going to return the result (even though the actual action is not marked `async`) until all tasks have finished.

Is it possible to use `async` to allow for concurrency here without forcing multithreading?

Comment: Rather than running the job in the asp.net website, you might want to run it on some other service

Comment: `async` is only marginally related with multithreading. You should read Stephen Cleary's blog on the subject. But I don't understand what you mean by "no impact on the data"...

Comment: I need to send analytic data to a web service I don't care when it happens and it's result should not affect the response to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async merely allows the thread to be returned to the pool should it enter a wait-state. This generally occurs with I/O operations, either local (reading/writing files on the filesystem) or remote (such as a web request to an API or a database query). As you correctly discerned, it has nothing to do with multiprocessing or background processing, which both are entirely separate concepts.

As far as spawning new threads, goes, that's actually extremely dangerous in the context of a web application. No web application should ever manually spawn threads. However, it wouldn't help you regardless, as the thread must still run within the context of the request pipeline, so you still wouldn't be doing anything in the background.

If you need to truly handle some task in the background and outside of the request-response cycle, then you need to utilize a tool for that purpose. A couple of good ones to look into are [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com/) and [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).